# Was there any grander purpose to the first victim in Cube?

Tags: cube

In *Cube* (1997), it's strongly implied that the participants in the Cube were chosen for a specific reason:

- Quentin McNeil is a competent but disturbed police officer who cracks under the pressure of the exercise.
- Joan Leaven is a mathematician who takes the first step to "solving" the Cube.
- David Worth designed a chunk of the Cube.
- Kazan is an autistic who has the ability to factor the primes necessary to solve the Cube.
- Dr. Helen Holloway is a doctor and conspiracy theorist.
- Rennes is a famous escape artist.

It's possible to debate Holloway or McNeil, but the other members have such unique background and talents that it's very likely they were specifically chosen as part of whatever grand design (if any) controls the Cube.

The first victim, credited as Alderson, dies before he meets anybody and doesn't live long enough to reveal his background. I'm curious if there was some intended uniqueness to him as well that didn't get revealed because of the brevity of his screentime.

Comment: I think the 3rd movie is a prequel that might have more information about the selection process.

Comment: I agree with eshier. If you haven't seen the sequel and the prequel, then answering your question would be a huge spoiler.

Answer (score -3):

It is revealed in the other films that a powerful organization gives people who have been sentenced to death the option of death, or having their memory partially erased and put in the cube. The reason I say partially is because they can still remember their names, occupation, family, etc., but none of them know how they got there or what they did to be put there (except, apparently, Worth. However, his job was designing the cube, and their jobs weren't erased).

Quentin is an unstable cop, and it is revealed he beats his wife, Rennes is a criminal who has escaped prison several times, Joan is a runaway, Worth is a bit of a pervert, Holloway is a bit unhinged, and Kazan is autistic. It's not really known what each of them did, but as you get to know the characters, it becomes clear that each of them are capable of committing some kind of crime that put them there.

Alderson is a pedophile. They have all done something.

Comment: Wait... where are you getting Alderson's crime?

Comment: Ernie Barbarash and Vincenzo Natali confirmed that Alderson was child molesting scum. Collin is right. The only thing I disagree with is the part about the government erasing their memory and shit. The movie was a metaphor for life. There is no secret conspiracy behind the cube.

Comment: I feel quite disturbed that you seem to be putting autistic people on the same level as paedophiles and wife-beaters.

Comment: So they give life sentences to people for being runaways, a bit of a pervert, a bit unhinged, or autistic? That seems… excessive.

Comment: @janusBahsJacquet Although, given the events of *Cube Zero*, there's some plausibility.

Comment: As F1Krazy points out, I think you're saying something you don't mean here. But if you can source the bit where Alderson is a pedophile, this is a valid answer and I'll accept it.